# Find the maximum number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `send_request()` function that pulls the data in csv format.

```
from pull_data import send_request
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

def max_nb_rows(season_slug, urls_ws):
    date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    for i in range(100):
        d = []
        response = send_request(season_slug, url_ws, date).content
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))
max_nb_rows('2015-2016-regular', 'cumulative-player-stats')
```

I want to find the maximum number of rows for `df` for 100 consecutive days. How could I do that?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Normally, I would have to do it, but there's a lot a data and you will need to login and pay something. Just take in account  that `df` is well defined. Sorry in advanced!!

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand question - how I know 100 consecutive days? Do you want check each df? Without data it is really hard answer.

Comment: Assume I have 100  different dfs for the 100 consecutive date, I want to find the one which have the maximum number of rows. I don't think you need any data to implement such thing. You just need to assume that each `df` exist and have a certain number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need filter from today first and then get max count by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), which sorted output, so need first value selected by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
def max_nb_rows(season_slug, urls_ws):
    lens = []
    date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    for i in range(100):
        d = []
        response = send_request(season_slug, url_ws, date).content
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))
        lens.append(df.loc[df['Date'] > date, 'Date'].value_counts().iat[0])
    return max(lens)
max_nb_rows('2015-2016-regular', 'cumulative-player-stats')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'Date':pd.to_datetime(['2017-10-21','2017-10-21','2017-10-21','2017-10-25','2017-10-25','2017-10-28'])})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D       Date  E
0  a  4  7  1 2017-10-21  5
1  b  5  8  3 2017-10-21  3
2  c  4  9  5 2017-10-21  6
3  d  5  4  7 2017-10-25  9
4  e  5  2  1 2017-10-25  2
5  f  4  3  0 2017-10-28  4
```

---

```
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
a = df.loc[df['Date'] > date, 'Date'].value_counts().iat[0]
print (a)
2
```

Detail:

```
print (df.loc[df['Date'] > date, 'Date'])
3   2017-10-25
4   2017-10-25
5   2017-10-28
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (df.loc[df['Date'] > date, 'Date'].value_counts())
2017-10-25    2
2017-10-28    1
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: You will need to increment the date from today.